# AWS Api Gateway return only response attributes defined in the model

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have a an API Gateway setup with http integrations and have defined request and response models. However, when the downstream service returns response attributes that are not defined in the response model API Gateway includes them in the response as well. Is there a way to make API Gateway only return the response attributes defined in the model and drop all other response attributes returned from the downstream service?